# SOQL query for Map of Lists

Tags: soql, community

I'm trying to use a Map of List in a query to select some specific records like that for example:

```
ID   String 
1      a
1      b 
2      c
2      d 
2      b
```

my Map<id,String> contains

```
id = 1, List("a","b")
id = 2, List("c")
```

the result that I want to achieve is :

```
ID   String 
1      a
1      b 
2      c
```

can I do this in one query and use this map in a query?

Comment: Yes you can, all you need to do is Make a Map<Id, List<String>> you loop on the queried records and populate your map and list accordingly

Comment: you misunderstood me, I want to create a query that uses my map(that I already created) as a condition on the first table to get the result that I wrote

Comment: btw I can loop over my map and make a selection every time, but I will make to many requests, I'm trying to find a better way

Answer (score 1):

You **cannot have the following structure** in a Map collection because the map key (*ID in this case*) will be always unique. Adding value for an existing key (or ID) in a map collection will overwrite the current value.

```
ID   String 
1      a
1      b 
2      c
```

If you really need it this way, then consider creating a apex class with the 2 variables and create a list of the class instances.

But, if you want to consolidate the list values from the map collection and query a different sobject, then you can collect all the values in the map into a single `List<String>` and use it in the SOQL query. Look at the sample code snippet below (*assuming `inputMap` as the `Map<Id, List<String>>` mentioned in your question*):

```
List<String> consolidatedList = new List<String>();
for(List<String> ls: inputMap.values()){
  for(String str: ls){
    consolidatedList.add(str);
  }
}

// Replace SObject, <field> & <fields> with appropriate values.
Map<ID, SObject> m = new Map<ID, SObject>([SELECT Id, <fields> FROM SObject WHERE <field> IN :consolidatedList]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no. SOQL query clauses must be explicitly defined. You cannot have a binding that provides the field to be interrogated, only the possible value(s).

However, the longer answer is that you can use your map to generate appropriate clauses in your SOQL query as long as it is a dynamic one. This does, however, have the drawback that a dynamic query doesn't support expressions in binding clauses (unlike static SOQL).

Faced with this the only really viable approach is to dynamically generate the entire query, along the following lines (noting that there are actual SOQL query length limits that may come into play if your map has a lot of data in it):

```
Map<Id, List<String>> values = ...;
List<String> conditions = new List<String>();

for (Id id : values.keySet()) {
    List<String> params = new List<String>();

    for (String param : values.get(id)) {
        params.add(String.escapeSingleQuotes(param));
    }

    conditions.add('Id = \'' + id +
        '\' AND Some_Field__c IN (\'' +
        String.join(params, '\', \'') + '\')');
}

String query = 'SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE (' +
    String.join(conditions, ') OR (') + ')';
```

At the end of this you have a query that doesn't use bindings but that does include the various conditions that ensure that the object ID and its field match the entries in the map.

Comment: very helpful, thanks